# Export an EPPlus Excel MemoryStream to a PDF

Tags: c#

I have a method which uses EPPlus to create an Excel file from a MemoryStream, now I need to export that Excel File to a pdf. Is there a way to either export the excel to a pdf or a way to export the memory stream to another excel workbook library?

This is my excel export method

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("export/{id}")]
        public IActionResult Export(int id)
        {
            MemoryStream response = _salidaService.Export(id);
            return File(response, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", $"Reporte Salida - {DateTime.Now}.xlsx");
        }
```

And this is the exportPDF method i have been trying using many different libraries like aspose.cells and Spire.Xls, in this case I was trying Spire.Xls

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("exportpdf/{id}")]
        public IActionResult ExportPDF(int id)
        {
            MemoryStream result = _salidaService.Export(id);
            Workbook wb = new Workbook();
            wb.LoadFromStream(result);
            MemoryStream response = new MemoryStream();
            wb.SaveToStream(response);
            return File(response, "application/pdf", $"Reporte Salida - {DateTime.Now}.pdf");
        }
```